# Handling errors when inputting dates

Tags: python, error-handling

I have a Python script that is asking the user for input of today's date. The method I am using is giving me an error which I'm finding confusing for me to figure out the error. What I'm trying to do is ask the user to input today's date and then output a message if the date is not in the format "mm/dd/yyyy". Any advice on the code and error would be helpful.

```
from datetime import date
todays_date = input("Enter today's date: ")
try:
    todays_date = date.strftime(todays_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
except ValueError:
    print("Error: must be in mm/dd/yyyy ")
    input = input("press 1 to try again or 0 to exit: ")
    if input == "0":
        sys.exit()
print("Today's date is {todays_date}")
```

**Error**

```
todays_date = date.strftime(todays_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
TypeError: descriptor 'strftime' for 'datetime.date' objects doesn't apply to a 'str' object
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's `strptime` and not `strftime` that is needed here. They have opposite functions

```py
from datetime import date
todays_date = input("Enter today's date: ")
try:
    todays_date = date.strptime(todays_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
except ValueError:
    print("Error: must be in mm/dd/yyyy ")
    input = input("press 1 to try again or 0 to exit: ")
    if input == "0":
        sys.exit()
print(f"Today's date is {todays_date}") # added f to correct string formatting
```

Answer (score 0):

you cannot use `strftime`in your case, because you have a string format.
Instead, try using strptime:

```py
from datetime import datetime
todays_date = datetime.strptime(todays_date, "%m/%d/%Y")
```